# How do I print the sum of X numbers output by heapq.nlargest?

Tags: python

I'm working on a small practice project and I couldn't find an answer for this. I'd like to roll 4d6, drop the lowest, and add the remaining three together. I've found that heapq.nlargest can find the highest N numbers for me, but I can't figure out how to sum the output of that into one number.

So far, my unfinished code looks like this:

```
import random
import heapq

print "How many stats would you like to roll?" 
dice = input

for i in range(dice()):
    roll1 = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll2 = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll3 = random.randint(1, 6)
    roll4 = random.randint(1, 6)
    allrolls = (roll1, roll2, roll3, roll4)
    high3 = heapq.nlargest(3, allrolls)
```

Comment: The `sum` function. How do you know `heapq.nlargest` and not the `sum` function? It takes any iterable and sums it, and `heapq.nlargest` returns an iterable (`list` to be precise).

Comment: Mind you, in this case `heapq.nlargest` is gaining you very little (it's mostly useful when you need a minority of the values from a larger list). `sum(allrolls) - min(allrolls)` or `sum(sorted(allrolls)[-3:])` would likely be more efficient, both theoretically and practically.

Comment: I've found an answer on here about a different thing that asked about how to print the x largest numbers of a small list, and it worked well. Thanks for the more efficient version!

Answer (score 0):

[The `sum` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#sum):

```
high3sum = sum(high3)
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this line to the end of your loop:

```
    print sum(high3)
```

The Python [`sum`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#sum) built-in will sum the values of an iterable. The [`heapq.nlargest`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/heapq.html#heapq.nlargest) method returns an iterable.